# how to access catalina.sh file of tomcat8 in amazon linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have installed tomcat 8 using yum. Now I need to make some changes in catalina.sh file but I'am unable to locate it. it would be helpful if anyone could tell me the pathway or how to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, on AWS, afaik, the start script for tomcat is `/etc/init.d/tomcat[version]`, in your case `/etc/init.d/tomcat8`, so you might be able to adapt that to your liking.